# discord.py - add_role command keeps checking the selected member

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a /add_role command for my bot, and yesterday I found out that the permission format was messed up. when I tried it on an admin, it worked, so I think the issue is the bot is trying to check the selected members' permissions, I'm not sure how to perform it though, because I've tried ctx, interaction all of that stuff and it just errored. Any help? thanks

```
@bot.tree.command(name='add_role', description='Add a role to a user')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def kick(interaction,member : discord.Member,* , role: discord.Role):
    if member.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Successfully added role {role} to {member}.", color=0x38ff6a)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"You do not have permission to run this command.\nReason: missing 'Manage Roles' permission", color=0xff0000)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are taking an input of `member` and checking if the same `member` has `manage_roles` permission. To check the command user, use `interaction.user`.

```
@bot.tree.command(name='add_role', description='Add a role to a user')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def add_role_command(interaction, member: discord.Member, * , role: discord.Role):
    if interaction.user.guild_permissions.manage_roles: #  Changed to command user
        await member.add_roles(role)
    ...
```

Comment: i knew that was the issue, thanks for helping :)